# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse Listener

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using `CollapsingToolBarLayout` alongside with `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`, and they are working Fine altogether. I set my `Toolbar` to be fixed when I scroll up, I want to know if there is a way to change the title text of the Toolbar, when **`CollapsingToolBarLayout`** it is collapsed.

Wrapping up, I want two different **titles** when *scrolled* and when *expanded*.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 176):

I share the full implementation, based on @Frodio Beggins and @Nifhel code:

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    public enum State {
        EXPANDED,
        COLLAPSED,
        IDLE
    }

    private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

    @Override
    public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
        } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);
}
```

And then you can use it:

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
        Log.d("STATE", state.name());
    }
});
```

Comment: That's correct. But please not that using Proguard that enum is going to be translated in an integer value.

Comment: Also enums are a very nice way of ensuring type safety. You can't have State.IMPLODED because it doesn't exist (the compiler would complain) but with Integer constants you could use a value that the compiler has no idea is wrong. They're good as singletons also but thats another story.

Comment: @droppin_science for android enums check out [IntDef](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Replacing-Enums-with-Enumerated-Annotations)

Comment: public class State {
        public static final int EXPANDED = 1;
        public static final int COLLAPSED = 0;
        public static final int IDLE = 2;
    }

    private int mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

Comment: @DavidDarias Personally I find enums a much cleaner approach even with their overhead (commence argument here... :-)

Comment: in my case, add `if (i == 0 && appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange() != 0)` to avoid state change to `COLLAPSED` then change immediately to `EXPAND`. Because after `abs(i) = TotalScrollRange`  both `i`  and `TotalScrollRange` are `0`, so state change back to `EXPAND`.

Answer (score 109):

This solution works perfectly for me to detect `AppBarLayout` collapsed or expanded.

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

            if (Math.abs(verticalOffset)-appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange() == 0)
            {
                //  Collapsed


            }
            else
            {
                //Expanded


            }
        }
    });
```

Used `addOnOffsetChangedListener` on the `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: This fires collapsed on multiple occasions, also on expand.

Answer (score 38):

Hook a `OnOffsetChangedListener` to your `AppBarLayout`. When the `verticalOffset` reaches 0 or less than the `Toolbar` height, it means that CollapsingToolbarLayout has collapsed, otherwise it is expanding or expanded.

```
mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if(verticalOffset == 0 || verticalOffset <= mToolbar.getHeight() && !mToolbar.getTitle().equals(mCollapsedTitle)){
                    mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(mCollapsedTitle);
                }else if(!mToolbar.getTitle().equals(mExpandedTitle)){
                    mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(mExpandedTitle);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: it is not working for me. OnCollapse i want to enable the home button and on Expand hid the home button

Comment: The verticalOffset values seems to be zero when the toolbar is fully expanded, and then goes negative while collapsing. When the toolbar is collapsed, verticalOffset is equal to negative the toolbar height (-mToolbar.getHeight()). So... the toolbar is partially expanded "if (verticalOffset > -mToolbar.getHeight())"

Comment: In case anyone is wondering where the `appBarLayout.getVerticalOffset()` method is, you can call `appBarLayout.getY()` to retrieve the same value that's used in the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately Jarett Millard isn't right. Depending on your fitsSystemWindow configuration and StatusBar configuration (transparent) the `appBarLayout.getY()` it may be that `verticalOffset = appBarLayout.getY() + statusBarHeight`

Comment: setTitle in `onOffsetChanged` is giving me `requestLayout() improperly called by CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Has anyone noticed if mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(listener) is called repeatedly even if we are not actually interacting with the appbar? Or it's a bug in my layout / app where I am observing this behavior. Plz help!

Comment: Why do we have 2 options for listeners for it? Both BaseOnOffsetChangedListener and OnOffsetChangedListener . And one extends the other without adding anything... Also, is there any way to have a listener for the scroll-state of it, meaning that when the scroll started and when it becomes idle?

Comment: This is exactly  what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

This code worked for me

```
mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new   AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (verticalOffset == -mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() + mToolbar.getHeight()) {
                //toolbar is collapsed here
                //write your code here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Better answer than Nikola Despotoski

Comment: Seems to be not a reliable solution. I tested it and values on my device are the following: mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() = 1013, mToolbar.getHeight() = 224. So according to your solution verticalOffset in collapsed state must be -789, however it is equal to -693

Answer (score 17):

```
private enum State {
    EXPANDED,
    COLLAPSED,
    IDLE
}

private void initViews() {
    final String TAG = "AppBarTest";
    final AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        private State state;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (verticalOffset == 0) {
                if (state != State.EXPANDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Expanded");
                }
                state = State.EXPANDED;
            } else if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
                if (state != State.COLLAPSED) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Collapsed");
                }
                state = State.COLLAPSED;
            } else {
                if (state != State.IDLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Idle");
                }
                state = State.IDLE;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can get collapsingToolBar alpha percentage using below :

```
appbarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener( new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            float percentage = ((float)Math.abs(verticalOffset)/appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
            fadedView.setAlpha(percentage);
    });
```

For Reference : [link](https://androidcot.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-animation-header-fade-inout/)

Comment: This is a great answer as it gives a normalized offset. In my opinion, the API should have provided this directly instead of the `verticalOffset` pixel distance.

Comment: I want when AppBarLayout collapsed then View is hide and expanded View is show. So I use `val percentage = 1 - abs(verticalOffset).toFloat() / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange`. It work very well for me.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a **Kotlin** solution. Add an `OnOffsetChangedListener` to the `AppBarLayout`.

**Solution A:**

Add `AppBarStateChangeListener.kt` to your project:

```
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
import kotlin.math.abs

abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener : AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    enum class State {
        EXPANDED, COLLAPSED, IDLE
    }

    private var mCurrentState = State.IDLE

    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, i: Int) {
        if (i == 0 && mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED)
            mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED
        }
        else if (abs(i) >= appBarLayout.totalScrollRange && mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED)
            mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED
        }
        else if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE)
            mCurrentState = State.IDLE
        }
    }

    abstract fun onStateChanged(
        appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?,
        state: State?
    )

}
```

Add the listener to your `appBarLayout`:

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object: AppBarStateChangeListener() {
        override fun onStateChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?, state: State?) {
            Log.d("State", state.name)
            when(state) {
                State.COLLAPSED -> { /* Do something */ }
                State.EXPANDED -> { /* Do something */ }
                State.IDLE -> { /* Do something */ }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

**Solution B:**

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
        if (abs(verticalOffset) - appBarLayout.totalScrollRange == 0) { 
            // Collapsed
        } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            // Expanded
        } else {
            // Idle
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is working for me:

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    if (onStateChangeListener != null && state != State.EXPANDED) {
      onStateChangeListener.onStateChange(State.EXPANDED);
    }
    state = State.EXPANDED;
  } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
    if (onStateChangeListener != null && state != State.COLLAPSED) {
      onStateChangeListener.onStateChange(State.COLLAPSED);
    }
    state = State.COLLAPSED;
  } else {
    if (onStateChangeListener != null && state != State.IDLE) {
      onStateChangeListener.onStateChange(State.IDLE);
    }
    state = State.IDLE;
  }
}
```

Use addOnOffsetChangedListener on the AppBarLayout.

Comment: Can you share your complete code? What is State.EXPANDED etc?

Answer (score 2):

This code is working perfect for me. You can use percentage scale How you like

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
    double percentage = (double) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / collapsingToolbar.getHeight();
    if (percentage > 0.8) {
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Collapsed");
    } else {
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Expanded");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution in Kotlin:

```
abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener : OnOffsetChangedListener {
    enum class State {
        EXPANDED, COLLAPSED, IDLE
    }

    private var mCurrentState =
        State.IDLE

    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, i: Int) {
        mCurrentState = if (i == 0) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED)
            }
            State.EXPANDED
        } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.totalScrollRange) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED)
            }
            State.COLLAPSED
        } else {
            if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE)
            }
            State.IDLE
        }
    }

    abstract fun onStateChanged(
        appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?,
        state: State?
    )
}
```

Here is the listener:

```
  appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarStateChangeListener() {
        override fun onStateChanged(
            appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?,
            state: State?
        ) {
            if(state == State.COLLAPSED){
                LayoutBottom.visibility = View.GONE
            }else if(state == State.EXPANDED){
                LayoutBottom.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CollapsingToolBarLayout you can put this

```
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, android.R.color.transparent));
collapsingToolbar.setTitle(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Toolbar offset value get -582 when collapse, on expand=0
So I find value by setting offsetvalue in Toast & change code accordingly.

```
 mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if(verticalOffset == -582) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "collaped" + verticalOffset, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Collapsed");
            }else if(verticalOffset == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "expanded" + verticalOffset, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("expanded");
            }
        }
    });
```