# how to gone toolbar menu when collapsed appBarLayout in android

Tags: android, android-view

I want **gone** `toolbar` Menu when **collapsed** `appBarlayout`, but I don't know how can it.
**My code is here:**

```
    public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment implements Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener ... 

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

...
}
    @Override
    public int getMenu() {
        return R.menu.search;
    }
```

**XML codes :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sepandar.xengine.fragment.MainFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <com.sepandar.xengine.views.XTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/xTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

            <com.api.common.widget.MyToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xTab"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.nt.googleplaysearch.views.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want when Collapsed **appBarLayout**, `gone` `public int getMenu()`, and when expand show this `public int getMenu()`.

How can I it?

Comment: can you put your related XML file which contain to toolbar and appbar code

Comment: @BhunnuBaba, please see my update post! can you help me?

Comment: once try to addOnOffsetChangedListener with appBarLayout

Comment: @BhunnuBaba, can you send me code? please

Comment: @BhunnuBaba, hey man are you here?

Comment: see this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682310/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-collapse-listener

Answer (score 0):

Use AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener to get appbar status {expand/collapse},
Then hide appbar menu on offset value change.

Answer (score 0):

use this `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` insted of `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` in `MyToolbar` it was work with `RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView` as second element in `CoordinatorLayout`
wrap your `ViewPager` in `NestedScrollView`