# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse Listener not working

Tags: android, android-toolbar, event-listener, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using `CollapsingToolBarLayout` alongside with `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout` and `Toolbar` with `EditText`, and they are working Fine altogether. Now, I want to get the **Collapsing State** of the layout. I have tried some implantation but they doesn't work for me.

Here is my code :

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_id"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Design.Home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:background="@drawable/b1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="285dp">

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <EditText
                    android:hint="Enter your search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </EditText>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**I have use this method from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682310/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-collapse-listener?fbclid=IwAR3vwRfBNxq05pyJy7bROgqlFop6OIxxo22Siw2upyxwZ1m4IlA8k0VV62Q) :**

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    public enum State {
        EXPANDED,
        COLLAPSED,
        IDLE
    }

    private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

    @Override
    public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
        } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);
}
```

**In on create method I have use this :**

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
        Log.d("STATE", state.name());
    }
});
```

**I have also tried another way :**

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

        if (Math.abs(verticalOffset)-appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange() == 0)
        {
            //  Collapsed
            Log.d("STATE", "Collapsed");
        }
        else
        {
            //Expanded
            Log.d("STATE", "Expanded");
        }
    }
});
```

None of this is working for me